# Nesting promises: make two promise calls back to back, passing values

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am currently building a license system for my electron applications. But I haven't been successful with the following:

1. Make a promise to prompt user for input (electron-prompt module)
2. Make an ajax call to server right after
3. Evaluate response (either a 1\n or 0\n from server-side script)

The headache comes to running the ajax call after getting the userinput from prompt (which is structured as a promise) and actually wait for it to finish.

Until now, I have tried to restructure my promises, as such:

(1)

```
prompt().
  then(ajax()).
    then(evaluate()).
      catch()
```

(2)

```
prompt().
  then(ajax().
         then(evaluate())).
    catch()
```

This is currently where i am, where the ajax function does not return anything to pass on.

First is the prompt, which works accordingly, returning its value.

```
function activeValidation(){
    try{
        prompt({
            title: "Enter key",
            label: "Enter your key",
            value: "",
            alwaysOnTop: true,
            autoHideMenuBar: true,
            inputAttrs: {
                type: 'text'
            },
            type: "input"
        })
```

Headache is within this segment, the ajax one.

```
        .then(function(userinput){
            return new Promise(function(resolve,userinput){
            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            req.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200){
                    resolve(req.responseText);          
                }
            }
            req.open("GET","someCGIscript?key="+userinput,true);
            req.send();
            }).then(function(response){
                if(response == "1\n"){
                    runProgram();
                }
                else{
                }
        }).catch(function(e){
            console.error(e);
            terminate();
        })});               
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log(e.name);
        console.log(e.message);
        terminate();
    }
}
```

I have tried printing the value of the ajax Promise from `resolve(req.responseText);` but returns undefined in the following segment.

After that I tried to restructure the two promises (nested and as .then of the first promise), no luck.

I believe this is a matter of structuring the promises correctly, but I am still a novice to Promises, atleast in js :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a parameter mismatch in your `new Promise` callback function. The second parameter has nothing to do with `userinput`, but is a reject-callback that is provided to you (in case you need it). By calling it `userinput` you lose access to the actual value of `userinput` as it was passed one line above it.

As a consequence the HTTP request will be to something like `someCGIscript?key=function () { [native code] }`, which obviously results in an undesired HTTP response.

So in the `new Promise` callback function parameter list, either call it `reject` or just omit it entirely.

Answer (score 0):

check this snippet. hope this will help you. prompt will handle the user input by itself. so when you received the input do the ajax call and grab the server response. this works as you wish and as far as I understood your question.

```
    const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
    const path = require('path')
    const prompt = require('electron-prompt'); // assume that this is what you use 
    var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest; 

    let mainWindow

    function createWindow() {

    prompt({
        title: 'Prompt example',
        label: 'License Key:',
        value: 'xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx',
        inputAttrs: {
        type: 'Key'
        },
        type: 'input'
    })
        .then((r) => {
        if (r === null) {
            console.log('user cancelled');
        } else {
            var data = {key: r}; // accepting the user input
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.withCredentials = true; 
            xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
            if (this.readyState === 4) {
                console.log(this.responseText)
                console.log(JSON.parse( this.responseText).status===1?'License complete':'Re enter a valid key')// key validation with the server response
            }
            });

            xhr.open("POST", "https://76c6d974-0305-4a40-b499-6b3efee4938f.mock.pstmn.io/license");
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");  

            xhr.send(JSON.stringify( data));
        }
        })
        .catch(console.error);


    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
        preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    })

    mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')

    mainWindow.on('closed', function () { 
        mainWindow = null
    })
    } 
    app.on('ready', createWindow)
```

good luck! vote if this helps to make it easy to others to find.